# What are the best planting conditions for primula seeds?

Tags: flowers, seeds, optimal-conditions, planting-times

Can anyone help me how to plant these primula seeds? I live in Cincinnati, Ohio. They will be in a greenhouse and this is what I need to know.

What size trays do I need?

Should I cover them?

What time is best for planting?

What should the temperatures and the humidity be?

[image]

Comment: Where are you in the world? - this particular mix of Primula is one intended to flower December through to March, usually sown in July, but what climate zone  you're in makes a difference

Comment: I looked these up - I'm surprised the supplier does not give information on how to grow these from seed, but this link https://www.syngentaflowers-us.com/product/flower/70007968 has an embedded link to a  pdf culture document within it - its obviously intended for professional growers, but might be worth reading. Otherwise,  there's a phone number at the bottom - I'd be inclined to contact Syngenta and ask for advice - you have pretty cold winters where you are.

Comment: Hi Claire! I took the information from your comments and edited it into the question, in order to keep it in one place, and because comments aren't permanent. I also rotated the picture. It looked sideways to me, unless that's the way you meant it, in which case I should have left it alone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leave sowing until your early spring. Scatter the small seed (mixing with small quantity of sand may help) onto the surface of a rough peat mix and press into the surface lightly, do not cover. Temperatures cool, water by misting, only as necessary to maintain dampness, rather than soaking. Please explain what you mean by "modules"; do you mean what trays or pots to sow in?

Comment: Yes by modules I mean trays, sorry. How big should they be?

Comment: Small shallow trays to begin with, just a small pot if you only have a few seeds, then transplant to a larger pot or tray when they reach 4-leaf stage.